# how to use IIF in c# data binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to convert online from VB.NET to C# in ASP.NET

this is the line

```
<asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# IIf(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NewPrice") = 0, Eval("Price"),Eval("NewPrice"))%>'></asp:Label>
```

But I don't know how to use the IIF in c#!!

Did anyone use it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:Label 
    ID="PriceLabel" 
    runat="server" 
    Visible="false" 
    Text='<%# Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NewPrice")) == 0 ? Eval("Price") : Eval("NewPrice"))%>' 
/>
```

Comment: can you replace you answer with this , so it will be more helpfull for me and for the others : <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# ( Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NewPrice")) == 0) ? Eval("Price") : Eval("NewPrice") %>'></asp:Label>

Comment: Yeap, you are correct. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NewPrice") == 0) ? Eval("Price") : Eval("NewPrice") %>
```

Comment: Better use `==` otherwise it will always be false.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Good point, updated answer

Comment: that is the correct answer thanks.


can you replace you answer with this , so it will be more helpfull for me and for the others : 

<asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# ( Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NewPrice")) == 0) ? Eval("Price") : Eval("NewPrice") %>'></asp:Label>